# Layering Elements Blurred at Different Percentages in Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image]

My designer gave me the following specs, where he produced a glow effect in Sketch by layering a series of colors with different blur %s. Does anyone know how to replicate this in Swift UI? The regular blur property only has a radius input: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/blur(radius:opaque:)

Answer (score 3):

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func glow() -> some View {
        self
            .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 0.5, saturation: 0.5, brightness: 1))
            .background {
                self
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 207/360, saturation: 0.7, brightness: 0.94))
                    .blur(radius: 4)
            }
            .background {
                self
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 214/360, saturation: 0.8, brightness: 1))
                    .blur(radius: 2)
            }
            .background {
                self
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 214/360, saturation: 0.8, brightness: 0.94))
                    .blur(radius: 12)
            }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Following")
            .font(Font.body.smallCaps())
            .glow()
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
    TestView()
        .padding()
        .background(Color(white: 0.06))
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
)
```

Result:

[image: the word "Following" in small caps with a glow effect]